# java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host

Tags: java, rmi

I am trying to run a RMI Application. I have started the the rmiregistry using the following command:
*rmiregistry 6789*.

Now I ran the server application in eclipse passing the the following VM arguments:
-Djava.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContextFactory
-Dava.naming.provider.url=rmi://localhost:6789

The following error message is thrown:
*javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 172.17.209.154; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]*

*172.17.209.154* is the IP of my machine.

Can any one pinpoint as to what is the error.

Answer (score 2):

Letter 'j' is missing in second VM argument *-D**j**ava.naming.provider.url=rmi://localhost:6789*